# What's the shortcut in outlook to search the currently selected e-mail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I imagine it's the same in all versions of outlook but I am using 2013.

I do a search and then click an e-mail, within that e-mail I want to search for a keyword. Normally I'd expect it to be CTRL+F but this forwards the e-mail. CTRL+G opens find&replace so almost there, but googling tells me to use CTRL+E or F3 and these just highlight the e-mail search box, not find within the e-mail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the email (preview pane doesn't work) then press F4.

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Outlook-2013-3e1090f6-a616-42db-abf5-269ca3d553ee

Comment: That is very annoying, I have just found CTRL+G, ALT+D will do it with the preview pane open but not ideal.

Comment: I share your sentiment, unfortunately that's the only way I've found. Microsoft really wants us to open emails..I also hate the fact that searching Contacts or the main windows is F3 but it's F4 to search in the actual mail you opened. And it's not like F3 has a different function...